# EF Core: how to apply the last migration to another database?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have 2 databases, development and production.
I added a new entity, added a migration then updated the development database.
It worked, development database has the new table.
I switched the database in my configuration to the production database.
I used `Update-Database` command from `Package Manager Console` but nothing happened.
My production database still doesn't have the new table.

What now?
What is the valid workflow for such scenario?

BTW, both databases already contain structure and data. The production database contains more recent data, the development database is one migration ahead.

UPDATE: I tried to revert the last migration on development database, it worked. Then I tried to apply it again on production. Didn't work. It seems like it refuses to apply the same migration again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

I assumed when I change the runtime profile for production the file `appsettings.Production.json` will be loaded on migration.

It didn't happen. The migration used `appsettings.Development.json` instead.

I changed the connection string in my `appsettings.Development.json` file to the production database and it worked.

It's weird, when I debug the web application it respects the settings. It either uses the development or production settings, as selected in Visual Studio. Migrations just use the development file.

If there's a cleaner way (IDK, tell the `Update-Database` command to use a different `appsettings` file), please let me know in comment.